# Which implementation need to be selected in Groovy, for this problem?

Tags: groovy

I have been learning Groovy for a week, but I have a problem: I need to store the combinations of words to the corresponding ascii values. For example the combinations of the word "the" and the sum of the ascii values of each characters is 10(not exactly,but still for example).

There are, obviously, other words where the sum of ascii values is 10. I want a data structure where I can look up the value 10 and get the words where the sum of the ascii values is 10. I can't do this in Groovy Map, because the key value should be unique. How to do this in Groovy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this as well:

```
def words = [ 'the', 'het', 'love', 'groovy' ]

words.groupBy { ( it as char[] ).collect { it as int }.sum() }
```

That gives you the map:

```
[321:[the, het], 438:[love], 678:[groovy]]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply to my second question regarding Groovy :-)

Comment: after seeing this, i guess i have to master Groovy closures very very well:):)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small example that initiates a `Map` that returns an empty `List` in case a key is requested for the first time using the `withDefault` method:

```
def map = [:].withDefault { [] }

map[10] << 'the'
map[10] << 'as'
map[20] << 'from'

assert map[10] == ['the', 'as']
assert map[20] == ['from']
```

Comment: How does this works? If we call withdefault with the closure an empty list, then how deos this converts the map function?

Answer (score 1):

A map of Int to List of String should fix this. Simply append the words having the same sum, to the list corresponding to a key.

Answer (score 1):

You need a multi-map data structure. [One](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/index.html) can be found in Apache Commons, [another one](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) in Guava.

In Groovy you can use a simple `Map` of `int` -> `list`, with default value for convenience.